# SQLite database running AsyncTask, how to use

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a fundamental confusion about SQLite. Do I make a database instance in the main? Does SQLite run on a background thread or do I have to put it in an AsyncTask? (If so, should it be the same asynctask as the one retrieving information?)

I am parsing an HTTP POST in an AsyncTask in my MainActivity(I get a list of vehicles whose information needs to be monitored), and I would like to put this ArrayList into an SQLite database.

How do I implement this? Right now I have an inner class extending the AsyncTask in MainActivity and a separate java file DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper.

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "vehicleManager";

    // Vehicle table name
    private static final String TABLE_VEHICLE = "vehicle";

............. code
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I do, I create a class called `Database` which is `static` and have all queries and all database access go through it. And if I need anything, I create a `static` function inside that `Database` class which executes whatever specific query I need and returns a `Cursor` which then I deal with in the code. This way, if I need to change any query, I only have to change one location, not run around my code trying to find all instances.

The `Database` class creates an instance of the `SQLiteHelper` class inside it when I call `Database.open(context)`. And of course all calls to `Database` are from an `AsyncTask` or a second thread.

Again, that my personal design, feel free to do like it or come up with your own.

```
public final class Database {

    private static SQLHelper sqlhelper = null;
    private static SQLiteDatabase database = null;
    private static Context context = null;

    /** Prevents Instances */
    private Database(){};

    /**
     * Initiates the Database for access
     * @param context Application context
     */
    public static void initiate(Context context){
        if (sqlhelper == null)
            sqlhelper = new SQLHelper(context);

        if (Database.context == null)
            Database.context = context;
    }

    /**
     * Opens the database for reading
     * @throws SQLException if the database cannot be opened for reading
     */
    public static void openReadable() throws SQLException{
        if (database == null)
            database = sqlhelper.getReadableDatabase();
    }

    /**
     * Opens the database for writing
     * Defaults to Foreign Keys Constraint ON
     * @throws SQLException if the database cannot be opened for writing
     */
    public static void openWritable() throws SQLException{
        if ((database == null)? true : database.isReadOnly()) {
            openWritable(true);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Opens the database for writing
     * @param foreignKeys State of Foreign Keys Constraint, true = ON, false = OFF
     * @throws SQLException if the database cannot be opened for writing
     */
    public static void openWritable(boolean foreignKeys) throws SQLException{
        database = sqlhelper.getWritableDatabase();
        if (foreignKeys) {
            database.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;");
        } else {
            database.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF;");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Closes the database
     */
    public static void close(){
        if (database != null){
            database.close();
            database = null;
        }
        if (sqlhelper != null){
            sqlhelper.close();
            sqlhelper = null;
        }
    }

    /* Add functions here */
    public static Cursor selectNames(){
        openReadable();
        return database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM names", null);
    }
}
```

---

```
final class SQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "core.db";

    //private final Context context;

    SQLHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        //this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        // Create the tables
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db){
        super.onOpen(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
}
```

---

And for access from Activity:

```
Database.initiate(getBaseContext());
Cursor c = Database.selectNames();
```

And from Fragment:

```
Database.initiate(getActivity());
Cursor c = Database.selectNames();
```

Comment: I don't know much about Cursors but what advantage does it give over doing something like simply returning ArrayList<Vehicle> or even HashMap<VehicleID, Vehicle>

Comment: None, do as the code needs, I have some functions that return Cursors, some other that return a single custom made object, and others that return array of objects and finally a list of objects. That's the beauty, make the function as specific as that code needs, and if you need it anywhere else, just use it again. And in the future if you modified your database, you just have to modify one query at one location.

Comment: Static does not seem to be working for me. How are you referencing the database or whatever? I have
public void addVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {

  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
....}      It is complaining about the this. call

Comment: I tried to do this without static and I am getting runtime errors. I really don't know how to do this static-ly

Comment: in your code you have SQLhelper, is that supposed to be SQLiteOpenHelper?

Comment: `SQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper` the second class in the code provided :D Have a closer look at the code, when all is good, please don't forget to accept the answer :) Cheers.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32519/discussion-between-benzabill-and-luckyme)

Answer (score 2):

It's better if you load/save to the database from a backround thread.
The calls to sqlite are synchronous which means that they can block your UI thread.

You can use the same asynctask or another, this has to do with your app's design and what you want to do. The important thing is not running the query from the main thread.

Comment: so i have my database code in a separate java file. I should create a database in my main, and then update in asynctask? or put the asynctask in my database code

Comment: @benzabill You can create public function in that class which saves data to your database.

Comment: could you give an example, @J1and1

Answer (score 1):

As @Plato mentioned you can save/read data from `AsyncTask` and in your comments you asked for example how to create public function in your database `class` so here it is:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// All Static variables
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "vehicleManager";

// Vehicle table name
private static final String TABLE_VEHICLE = "vehicle";

//public function to do stuff with the database
public static void saveVehicle(/*arguments*/){ //note you should somhow pass data you want to save.... you can create as many arguments as you need
     //Sql save logic with those arguments
}
```

And when you need to save the data you should call

```
DatabaseHandler.saveVehicle(/*arguments*/);
```

Please note that when you implement the method in your class you might want a return value to tell if the data was really saved.

Comment: alright, so I do not need to make a SQLite database in my main method and instead the database handler will have it?

also, what part should be in the asynctask? any call to the databasehandler class?

Comment: You will create all the methods inside that DatabaseHandler save/update etc. etc. and call them from any part of your code to read/write/update data.In the async task you will call something like DatabaseHandler.saveVehicle(/*arguments*/); of course you will need to modify this code to pass all the data that you want to save method